What does 気づいたら at the end of a sentence alone mean?
The character bought a weird item and one of his friends found out. Embarrassed, the character explains himself and says

最初はちょっとした興味本位で本当に好きというわけではなく気づいたらですね

"I bought it for curiosity, it's not like I like these things..."
I'm aware たら can mean たらいい but I don't think it makes sense to say this about himself and his buying choice?

It seems that you've been forgetting to check the answers recently. It's not necessary to do it immediately, but please make sure to either check the most valuable answer or indicate why you're not satisfied yet within a few days.

気付いたら by itself is a common set phrase meaning "before I knew (it)" or "by the time I noticed". It's used like this:

気付いたらもう夜だった。
Before I knew it, it was already night.

So your sentence is like this:

最初はちょっとした興味本位で、本当に好きというわけではなく、気づいたらですね…
At first, it was just out of curiosity, and it wasn't like I really liked it, (however) when I knew it...well, you know...

You have to imagine the final unsaid part of the sentence from the context. It's perhaps something embarrassing to him, so it can be something like "(before I knew it) I had come to love this".

I am not completely sure but here are some of my thoughts:
It seems to me that the speaker intentionally left out some things out. The full sentence would look like

最初はちょっとした興味本位で本当に好きというわけではなく気づいたら適当にに買っちゃったんですね


I think that "starting something for curiosity, and then like it, and then realize that(気づいたら) don't like.
Maybe, a text from a manga
